# Python - applying tupple to a function in functional toolz.pipe

Tags: python, functional-programming, toolz

I want to use a function which accepts some arguments in a toolz.pipe, but data input is a tuple. I know how to solve it, but I think there must be some solution in builtin python libraries or in toolz, I just wasnt able to find it.

Example:

```
def my_func(a, b):
    return a + b

result = pipe(
    (10, 20),
    my_func,
    ...,
)
```

> For those unfamiliar with `toolz`, `pipe` is something like:
>
> ```
> def pipe(val, *functions):
>     data = val
>     for fn in functions:
>         data = fn(data)
>     return data
> ```

### What I tried:

I know how to solve it, for example this way:

```
result = pipe(
    (10, 20),
    lambda x: my_func(*x),
    ...,
)
```

But I find this ugly and I'd like to be able to use some sort of `apply`
function which encapsulates that lambda. I defined mine `apply_` like this:

```
from toolz import pipe

def my_func(a, b):
    return a + b

def apply_(func):
    return lambda x: func(*x)

result = pipe(
    (10, 20),
    apply_(my_func),
)
print(result)
```

But this seems like something so basic, I'm almost convinced it must exist
in builtin python libraries or in `toolz` package..

### Question:

Is there some form of `apply` wrapper like I described above (`apply_`), which
I have overlooked?

Comment: what about `map`?

Comment: @Drey - I don't quite understand how that would be possible - can you post a piece of code?

Comment: `apply_` as you have written it is exactly what i would've done

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```
import toolz
import itertools

def my_func(a, b):
    return a + b


list(toolz.pipe(
    [(10, 20), (30, 40)],
    toolz.curry(itertools.starmap)(my_func)
))
```

The output:

```
[30, 70]
```

---

**Edit**
I was wrong with my intial solution, but I think [`itertools`'s `starmap`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap) is the way to go.

Comment: But this would just call my_func twice and with one parameter each time..

Comment: Your are right. I edited the post and now here is what I hope is what you were looking for.

Comment: I'm sorry, but you made it into a different problem - I don't want any mapping over a sequence, I just needed to "paste" a sequence into function's arguments, which is not what your solution does..

Comment: That is what `starmap` does - its pastes a sequence into function's arguments, e.g. it pastes (10, 20) into `my_func`. It would be kind of you to provide a minimal working example of what you want to do. But `pipe(
    (10, 20),
    lambda x: my_func(*x),
    ...,
)` and `pipe(
    [(10, 20)],
    toolz.curry(itertools.starmap)(my_func),
    ...,
)` produce the same results.

Comment: Well you wrote is yourself - I CAN'T use starmap when I have `(10, 20)` in pipe - your solution works only if I put the tuple into a list - which is NOT what I want. But you're right about the example, I didn't provide _complete_ working example. I'll fix that - somehow, because in my question, I'm asking how to do something which I don't know how to do, so _complete_ example doesn't make much sense. But I'll complete my `apply_` piece of code at least.

Answer (score 1):

toolz have the c.map that you can use:

```
import toolz as tz
from toolz import curried as c

tz.pipe(data, c.map(function), ...)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Curried `map(my_func)` has `(Iterable) -> Iterable` signature. You can see for yourself if you switch `apply_` in my example for `c.map` (and add `list` to pipe). It will try call `my_func` for each member of (10, 20) - which would not work, because `my_func` has signature `(param, param)` and `map` (curried or not) assumes it has only one parameter signature.

Answer (score 0):

Two years late but I think what you're looking for is reduce:

```
from toolz import pipe, partial, reduce
    
def my_func(a, b):
    return a + b

result = pipe(
    (10, 20),
    partial(reduce, my_func),
)
print(result)
```

Comment: That's interesting "hack", but it only works for 2-value tuples (which I used in the question for simplicity). It won't work for different number of values in the tuple..

Answer (score 0):

Seems like starmap as suggested elsewhere is a great approach, but you don't want to iterate over the elements of your tuple, you want the tuple to be the (only) element of an iterable:

```
from itertools import starmap
from operator import methodcaller as dot
from toolz.curried import partial, partition, pipe

def my_func(a, b, c):
    return f"a:{a}, b:{b}, c:{c}"

pipe(
    (1,2,3),
    partition(3),  # length of the tuple
    partial(starmap, my_func),
    dot("__next__"),
)
```

gives

```
'a:1, b:2, c:3'
```